Why doesn't Unity open the error script even though I click on the error in the console?
I reinstalled Unity on my computer. In the past, when I clicked on the error in the console, I would reach the incorrect line of code. Now when I click on the error in the console, nothing happens. What can I do so that when I click on the error in the console, I go to the wrong line?


There are some good suggested solutions on Unity forum for this issue here: https://discussions.unity.com/t/double-clicking-error-in-console-doesnt-go-to-line-in-vs-code-etc/775835/4

Thank you, I solved my problem. @Job_September_2020

Switching my game from Release Mode to Debug Mode solved my problem, as suggested by MBonKov on the Unity Forums.

